# mysql how to join to table

Tags: mysql

structure table1:

```
tb1_id   tb1_name
1        a
2        b
3        c
```

structure for table2:

```
id  name   tb1_id
1   a       ?
2   b       ?
3   c       ?
4   a       ?
5   a       ?
6   b       ?
```

Now lets guess here i have more then 10000 records in **table2** and like 1000 records in **table1** and i dont know the **tb1_id** here which i want to update table2 and set tb1_id as it is on table1.

for example it should look like(table2):

```
id  name   tb1_id
1   a       1
2   b       2
3   c       3
4   a       1
5   a       1
6   b       2
```

regards

Comment: mysql or sql server? they have different syntax when creating update with join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL,

```
update table2 a
inner join table1 b on
a.id=b.tb1_id
set a.tb1_id=b.tb1_id
```

For SQL Server,

```
update a
set a.tb1_id=b.tb1_id
from table2 a
inner join table1 b on
a.id=b.tb1_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Update from Join` syntax. Try this.

```
UPDATE table2 AS a
       JOIN table1 AS b
         ON a.name = b.tb1_name
SET    a.tb1_id = b.tb1_id
```